# Why I can't find syslanguages table in my sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

It is said this table is contained in 'master', but I couldn't find it.
Do somebody know the reason?
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Let me correct you. syslanguages is not a table; its a system view. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

well,I have found the answer by myself
Actually it is contained in master database however we cann't see it directly. We have to use master and select * from master.sys.syslanguges and it is done!